# WordPress archive/taxonomy location

Tags: wordpress, archive, permalinks, taxonomy, slug

I'm struggling with this, despite being *okay* at WordPress dev.

I've created a custom post type called **links**

I've also created a custom taxonomy called **link-type**

All works fine when using `archive.php` in the root of the theme.

However I want **links** to be a child *page* of resources so:

`example.com/links/` would become `example.com/resources/links/`

And clicking on a taxonomy term link for example `downloads` would take you to `example.com/resources/links/downloads/`

I'm aware of `has_archive` and `rewrite` and `with_front` and `slug` but can't understand how to use these to achieve the aforementioned structure.

As always, expert help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you register your post type, just add whatever you want to the slug in the rewrite argument, forward slashes *are* acceptable in slugs.

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    ...
    'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'resources/links',
        'with_front' => true
    ),
);
```

This will give you `https://example.com/resources/links/`, even if you have a page already at `https://example.com/resources/`.

I almost forgot, you'll need to make sure your flush your rewrite rules (this can be done programatically when the CPT is registered, or you can just go to your **Settings** > **Permalinks** option page and click <kbd>Save Changes</kbd> to accomplish the same thing one time.

Comment: This is great, thank you very much @Xhynk, exactly what I needed. Out of interest do we know what `with_front` does?

Comment: My pleasure! And it actually defaults to `true` so in this instance it may not be necessary. But you can read about it [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#rewrite). It just means if you have an additional path in your permalink structure, it will be included (like if you have `/blog/` it will be `/blog/cpt/` by default (true) or just `/cpt/` if set to false